# SAS Sum specific column that the name are stored in other column

Tags: sas

I have a data set like this :

```
 ID    I201401    I201402    ... I201411    I201412    START     END
 1       1           0              1          1      I201402  I201410
 2       0           0              0          1      I201401  I201408
 3       1           1              0          0      I201408  I201412
```

To explain the dataset simply each ID have a 1 or 0 in column I201401 through I201412 depending on certain factor. Depending on other factor I establish column START and END too. Not all ID have the same START and END value.

What I want to do is to create a other column that is the summation of the column mention in the START column through the END column. For quick understanding here is what the dataset should appear :

```
 ID               SUM
 1  (SUM of I201402 Throught I201410)
 2  (SUM of I201401 Throught I201408)
 3  (SUM of I201408 Throught I201412)
```

The thing is a don't really know how to specifies the sum function to use the value of column START and END to do is operation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how to do this without looping, but with an array and the `vname()` function, you should be able to do what you need:

```
data want (keep=id sum);
    set have;
    array var_array I201401--I201412;
    sum=0;
    do over var_array;
        if start le vname(var_array) le end then sum = sum + var_array;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: Being careful that your comparisons are valid mathematically (in this case it looks like they would be) this is a great solution.  I was thinking of a much more complicated answer, but this one looks like the right way to go.

Comment: This solution work great! I just mofifiy the if statement for    if start le vname(var_array) ge end then sum = sum + var_array;

Comment: Are you sure?  Unless I'm really misunderstanding something, that would always result in sum=0.